# Removing a fixed quantity from multiple "buckets" randomly

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose I have a set of $100$ elements split into $4$ buckets A-D as follows:

```
A: 10 elements
B: 20 elements 
C: 30 elements
D: 40 elements
```

I want to remove $k < 100$ elements out of these $100$ elements randomly.

What algorithm will give me the random number of elements $k_A, k_B, k_C,$ and $k_D$ to remove from the respective buckets, such that

- $k_A + k_B + k_C + k_D = k$, and
- each element in the set has the same probability of being removed?

Comment: To clarify, I guess one way to do this would be to shuffle all the elements together, remove $k$ randomly, and then put all remaining elements back into their respective buckets (assuming we can distinguish them somehow).

Comment: Draw a uniform number which indicates what bucket to draw from.

Comment: I actually want to be able to draw from all buckets. The idea is to remove $k$ randomly while being "fair" in the sense that all buckets are removed from (imagine the "elements" are units of money, and the buckets are people).

Comment: Ah, sure. Well in that case you can implement an algorithm in which you draw a uniform that indicates what bucket to draw from. Then you draw one ball from the respective bucket, draw a new uniform number etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

The criteria of "fairness" and exactly equal probability for all elements are not entirely compatible.

The expected value of the number of elements drawn from $A$ is $$k_A=k\cdot\frac{|A|}{100}$$ which is not in general an integer. So in order to take elements as evenly as possible, first take $\lfloor k_A\rfloor$ from $A$, $\lfloor k_B\rfloor$ from $B$, etc. Then you will have $r$ left over.

From this point there are many different options. For example, you can select $r$ of the non-empty buckets and take one from each. You could make a list of values of $\operatorname{frac}k_i$, sorted in descending order, then take one from the first $r$ sets on the list. You could randomly choose $r$ points on the interval $(0,\sum\operatorname{frac}k_i)$ and take elements from the sets corresponding to subintervals. All of these approaches have pitfalls and complications. It depends on what your priorities are, and what you consider fairest in this context.